# How does cron schedule jobs internally

Tags: symfony, cron

I am using symfony, and symfony has the functionality that can create and customize commands to execute some php code. but I have to manually type the command, this is I would not like to do. So I think of the cron. Hence I am using cron to manage my commands that are needed to be executed.

For example, I have two commands, Command A and Command B, they do need to be executed every minute. 
So, in the crontab file, here is the code:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php Command A  
* * * * * /usr/bin/php Command B
```

But I am not sure how does cron schedule those two jobs. Will they be executed in the same time? or Command A will be executed, and then Command B will be executed.

Many thanks for your help!!

Comment: Please tell me why are you doing this? Surely some other technology like a daemon would be better

Comment: @EdHeal because I am using symfony, and symfony has the functionality that can create and customize commands to execute some php code. but I have to manually type the command, this is I would not like to do. So I think of the cron job.

Comment: @EdHeal btw, i think its ugly vote

Comment: What does command do? Can it not wait around a bit?

Comment: Why not put a sleep 60 seconds less the execution time

Answer (score 0):

- Command A starts first
- Command B doesn't wait for Command A to finish and starts right after

So they run in parallel which means you can run into troubles depending on what your commands do. 
In that case you can use a main command that you call every minute and in turn calls the other commands however you want it.